# Periodic VolumeSnapshot in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-pvc, persistent-volume-claims

I wrote a **CronJob** that periodically takes volume snapshot of my **PVC**. Below is the **CronJob** file:

```
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: mycronjob
spec:
  schedule: "*/2 * * * *"   # Run the job every 2 minutes
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: webserver-container
            image: kubectl:latest
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - /app/script.sh
            volumeMounts:
            - name: script-volume
              mountPath: /app
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          volumes:
          - name: script-volume
            configMap:
              name: script-configmap
```

The **Volume Snapshot** file looks like this:

```
kind: VolumeSnapshot
metadata:
  name: snap-shot-test
spec:
  volumeSnapshotClassName: csi-snapclass
  source:
    persistentVolumeClaimName: my-test-apps
```

And here is the **script** file:

```
#!/bin/bash
kubectl apply -f volumesnapshot.yml
```

First time the cronjob is successfully executed, but after that it says
*volumesnapshot.snapshot.storage.k8s.io/snap-shot-test unchanged*

How can I periodically take volumesnapshot of a PVC with having latest 2 copies of the snapshot?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that what you describe mirrors the YAML files you shared; there is nothing that changes the name of the backup and therefore it will never create a new one.

If you want to make a backup of one PVC to another in a "raw" way with scripts, maybe think of a job that mounts 2 Volumes (source and destination) and executes a simple `cp -Rp /volume-source/* /volume-destination/`

Otherwise, if you want to get the job done right, consider using a tool like Velero.

https://velero.io/

Comment: obviously to make the copy dynamic, you will have to put some intelligence into the script to generate a new folder and copy the contents of the PVC into it.

Comment: Yeah, those are the yaml files.. I do not want a raw backup, rather I want to create K8 snapshots dynamically without using any third-party tool.. I think I need a script to change the name of snapshot everytime it executes

Comment: ok, with all these clarifications I would really tell you to customize the VolumeSnapshot; I saw that you already run the command inside a SH script, so it should be simple... I would generate a hash, associate it with a variable and with a SED I would change the name of the snapshot.

Comment: thanks. thats what we did and it worked. We appended current date to the volumesnapshot name and for optimization we deleted previous date sanpshots